# How to append the csv file in python through each loop of dates in screen scrapinng?

Tags: python, loops, csv, append, screen-scraping

This is the code that I am working on and I want to the code to iterate through scraping and dates in such a way that it does not overwrite the csv file and the new data is added after scraping through next set of dates. Please help me with it.
I tired different methods such as f.write()
and append as well for the same code but it gives me some or other error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from selenium import webdriver
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import numpy as np
import requests

def render_page(url,type):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\screen scraping codes\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(15)
    if type =="C":
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'wuSettings'))
        )
        element.click()
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="wuSettings-quick"]/div/a[2]')))
        element.click()
        time.sleep(15)
        r = driver.page_source
        driver.quit()
    if type=="F":
        r = driver.page_source
        driver.quit()
    return r

def hourly_scraper(page,dates,type):
    output = pd.DataFrame()

    for d in dates:
        url = str(str(page) + str(d))

        r = render_page(url,type)

        soup = BS(r, "html.parser",)
        container = soup.find('lib-city-history-observation')
        check = container.find('tbody')

        data = []
        data_hour = []
        for i in check.find_all('span', class_='ng-star-inserted'):
            trial = i.get_text()
            data_hour.append(trial)

        for i in check.find_all('span', class_='wu-value wu-value-to'):
            trial = i.get_text()
            data.append(trial)


        numbers = pd.DataFrame([data[i:i+7] for i in range(0, len(data), 7)],columns=["Temperature","Dew Point","Humidity","Wind Speed","Wind Gust","Pressure","Precipitation"])
        hour = pd.DataFrame(data_hour[0::17],columns=["Time"])
        wind = pd.DataFrame(data_hour[7::17],columns=["Wind"])
        condition = pd.DataFrame(data_hour[16::17],columns=["Condition"])

        dfs = [hour,numbers,wind,condition]

        df_final = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, left_index=True, right_index=True), dfs)
        df_final['Date'] = str(d)

        output = output.append(df_final)
        df_final.to_csv(r'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\screen scraping codes\123.csv',index=False)
        print(str(str(d) + ' finished!'))
       

    return output


page = "https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/in/ahmedabad/VAAH/date/"
#dates = ["2020-12-27","2020-12-28"]
d0 = datetime(2009, 1,1)
d1 = datetime(2009, 1,3)
dt = timedelta(days = 1)
dates = np.arange(d0, d1, dt).astype(datetime)

hourly = hourly_scraper(page,dates,"C")
```

Comment: An alternative would be to add the date and time to the filename. They could then be combined at a later stage. If you use the format `YYYY-mm-dd HH_MM_SS xxxxx.csv` then they would also be chronologically sorted in the folder by default.